# Find all the real roots of $P(Q(x))=0$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $$P(x)=x^2+\frac{x}{2}+b$$ and $$Q(x)=x^2+cx+d$$ be two polynomials with real coefficients such that $\displaystyle P(x)\cdot Q(x)=Q(P(x))$ for all real $x$. Find all the real roots of $P(Q(x))=0$.

---

I found out that
\begin{align}
x^4+x^3c+x^2d+\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{x^2c}{2}+\frac{xd}{2}+bx^2+bcx+bd&=\\x^4+x^3+2bx^2+\frac{x^2}{4}+bx+b^2+cx^2+\frac{cx}{2}+cb+d
\end{align}
After this I am stuck. I don't see any ideas now.

Any help is greatly appreicated.

Comment: can somone pls align my text correctly?

Comment: I aligned your equation. You can now obtain equations for your coefficients since the two sides have to be equal as polynomials.

Comment: I feel like it should be possible to give an elegant solution to this by using the equation $P(x) Q(x) = Q(P(x))$, just by substituting in specific values of $x$. For example, if $u$ is a solution to $P(Q(x)) = 0$, then:
$$P(Q(u)) Q(Q(u)) = Q(P(Q(u))$$
$$0 = Q(0)$$

which immediately implies that $d = 0$. I'll give this a go later but try to see if you can do something with this instead.

Comment: @AbhijeetVats you can exploit $Q(0)=0$ then $Q(P(0))=Q(b)=0$ to rewrite $Q(x)=x(x-b)$ then also $Q(P(b))=0$ so $P(b)=0$ or $b$ leading to $b=0,-\frac 12,-\frac 32$. Reporting in the equation discard spurious $b=0,-\frac 32$. Don't know if really faster than direct identification.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the approach I was thinking of.  I'd say that it's more elegant to do it that way than just finding the composition explicitly. Like, it feels cleaner but that may be just be an illusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the equation you've found gives
$$x^4+x^3(c+1/2)+x^2(d+c/2+b)+x(d/2+bc)+bd=x^4+x^3+(2b+1/4+c)x^2+(b+c/2)x+(b^2+cb+d)$$
Comparing coefficients, we get

- $c+1/2=1\implies c=1/2$
- $d+c/2+b=2b+1/4+c\implies d+1/4+b=2b+1/4+1/2\implies d=b+1/2$
- $d/2+bc=b+c/2\implies d/2+b/2=b+1/4\implies d=b+1/2$
- $bd=b^2+bc+d\implies b(b+1/2)=b^2+b/2+d\implies d=0\implies b=-1/2$
  So $P(x)=x^2+x/2+b=\frac{1}{2}(2x^2+x-1)$ and $Q(x)=x^2+cx+d=x^2+x/2$.

Now $P$ has two roots, $x=-1, 1/2$.
So roots of $P(Q(x))=0$ are the solutions to

- $Q(x)=-1\implies x^2+x/2=-1\implies x^2+x/2+1=0$ this has no real roots.
- $Q(x)=1/2\implies x^2+x/2=1/2\implies 2x^2+x-1=0\implies x=-1, 1/2$.